# What is the convergence rate of the minimum separation distance?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $\Omega$, denoted as $D = \{p_1,p_2,p_3\ldots \}$. Define the minimum seperation distance among first $n$ points of $D$ as
$$h(n) = \min_{1\le i,j\le n,i\ne j}\|p_i-p_j\|_2 .$$

I'd like to know the convergence rate of $h(n)$ as $n\to\infty$. Surely $h(n)\to 0$, but at what rate. Has it got anything to do with the dimension of the space. Is it $$h(n) = O(n^{-\frac{1}{m}})$$ os it simply $h(n) = O(1/n)?$

I feel there are some notions that I am not aware, which is the reason this question is puzzling me.

Comment: I think you are interested in $\max_D \min_{i,j}\|p_i-p_j\|$? right?

Comment: no. $h(n) = \min_{p_i,p_j\in E_n,p_i \ne p_j}\|p_i-p_j\|_2$

Comment: Is it just $h(n) = O(1/n)$?

Comment: My question could be really simple or silly, just that I don't know the answer. I am sure I am asking what I intended.

Comment: @Dirk : I thought Lipschitz domain means bounded already, but learnt just now that it isn't. So to add, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with a smooth boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is any bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^m$, Let $B_0$ be a ball which contains it, and let $B$ be a ball with the same center but with its radius increased by $1$. Say $R$ and $V$ are the radius and volume of $B$.

Fix $r < {\rm min}(\frac{1}{2}h(n), 1)$. Then the $r$-balls about the points $p_1$, $\ldots$, $p_n$ are disjoint, and as they are all contained in $B$ we have $nv \leq V$, where $v$ is the volume of a ball of radius $r$. Thus $nr^m \leq R^m$, so $r \leq Rn^{-\frac{1}{m}}$. As this is true of every $r < \frac{1}{2}h(n)$, we get $h(n) \leq 2Rn^{-\frac{1}{m}}$.

To see that $O(n^{-\frac{1}{m}})$ is best possible, let $\Omega$ be the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and form $D$ as the union, in order, of the sets $D_k = 2^{-k}L \cap \Omega \setminus (D_1 \cup \cdots \cup D_{k-1})$, where $L$ is the integer lattice in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $|D_1 \cup \cdots \cup D_k| = |2^{-k}L \cap \Omega| = 2^{km}$, so $h(2^{km}) \geq 2^{-k}$ (the minimum distance between points in $2^{-k}L \cap \Omega$). That is, for $n = 2^{km}$ we have $h(n) \geq n^{-\frac{1}{m}}$ in this example.

Comment: If I define $$r(n) = \sup_{x\in\Omega}\min_{1\le i \le n}\|p_i-x\|_2 $$, what would be the convergence rate of $r(n)$? Will this be the same as that of $h(n)$ or any faster? If this a very different question that needs a separate post?